# Is there a way to query the current reference count of a _com_ptr_t object?

Tags: c++, com

I'm having some issues (crashing) with a COM object that is wrapped in a `_com_ptr_t` template object.  I need to interrogate the object to see what the reference count is, because I'm pretty sure that the object is getting destroyed prematurely.

It would be even better if I could somehow hook into the `AddRef()` and `Release()` functions, but I can't seem to find where these are beyond the ones located in the `_com_ptr_t` class.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[_com_ptr_t](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b.aspx) wraps an [IUnknown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms691379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instance, but hides the return of **AddRef** and **Release** which would be the current reference count. [GetInterfacePtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9dec30w.aspx) should "lift the fog".